# send generated pdf to docusign and allow multiple signatures

Tags: docusignapi

i use docusign for the first time and need a solution.

I use a form, which will be filled out on my website (also attachments will be uploaded). This form should now be sent (maybe as PDF??) via API call to Docusign. There it should be signed. In some cases, a second signature is needed.

Once signed, the document should be emailed and stored in a cloud. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Tom, this is a very common scenario.
You can start by downloading our sample code that already gives you this particular use-case and very similar scenario. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email
This code is available in 6 different langs.
You would be making a few API calls, one to create the envelope, one to send it.
In order to store the completed document, you can use our connect service, which is a web-hook that can call back to your application with the information and the signed document to be stored where you want to store it. You can find information about DocuSign Connect in this link https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect

Comment: Thank you for your answer. yes I understand. I can use remote signing for the second signature.

But for the first signature my dynamically created PDF should be signed. How can I send the PDF to Docusign after generating?

Comment: the code I pointed you above shows you how to upload your document. Did you try to run this code?